# Managing Dates Query in ACCESS with SQL Server background

Tags: sql, sql-server, vba, date, ms-access

I am doing my project on ACCESS for the "front" part with the forms, and in SQL Server for the "back-end" part with the databases, everything works fine exect for one thing : I don't understand **how to filter Access's forms with SQL Server's date type**.

I have looked for everything on the web and all the solutions don't seems to work for my case (maybe because of the ACCESS/SQL Server env), things like :

```vb
Me.Form1.Filter = "[date born] = #" & Format("11/04/2022", "dd/mm/yyyy") & "#"
'with VBA directly
```

```sql
SELECT * FROM dbo_Person WHERE [date born] = Format('11/04/2022','dd/mm/yyyy') ;
-- with SQL Request from ACCESS on the table
```

but everytime I have the same issue: nothing is displayed even if there is rows who have this date in the right column. It is like if no row respected this condition even though it is not the case.
I'm guessing it may be an issue with SQL Server Date type who doesn't convert well on ACCESS.

[image: here is the data in the "date born" column]

That is how is desplayed by default in my ACCESS the dates of the column (my ACCESS software is setuped in French btw)

The data is well recognize as "not a String" because when I try to filter with a String an error appears.

Can someone help me to know where I missed something or misstyped something please ?

**Edit** : the Date column seems actually to be recognized as Short String in ACCESS, it may be the issue but still don't know how to fix because it is indeed a date type on sql server

[image: shows the type of the column in ACCESS]

"Texte court" can be translated to "short text" or short String

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Comment: MSSQL expect date format `mm/dd/yyyy`. So use `Format$(varDate, "\#mm\/dd\/yyyy\#")` to filter dates in MS-Access form.

Comment: @Harun24hr that is bad and incorrect advice. SQL Server doesn't expect `MM/dd/yyyy`, it uses the language of the `LOGIN` to determine how an ambiguous date format should be converted. For myself, `'05/19/2022'` would generate an error. For an unambiguous date, the formats `yyyyMMdd` or `yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:ss(.nnnnnnn)` should be used.

Comment: Access uses it own date time, and sql server date formats DO NOT MATTER ONE TINY bit. The simple issue is either the ODBD driver sees the column as Access date time, or it does not (end of story). Any and all date formats used in Access should 100% continue to work, and that is what the ODBC driver does (translates from sql server, or Oracle, or MySQL, or whatever system into Access date/time format). ZERO and I mean 100% ZERO ZERO changes are required to access client side code. The issue here is datetime2, and using the WRONG ODBC driver. Dumping datetime2, or updating ODBC is the fix here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, if you use data type *DateTime2* in SQL Server, that will be read as text in Access.

So, change that to *DateTime*.

Next, use the universal format yyyy-mm-dd when filtering date values:

```vb
FilterDate = DateSerial(2022, 4, 11)
Me.Filter = "[date born] = #" & Format(FilterDate, "yyyy\/mm\/dd") & "#"

' Linked table in Access:

Sql = "SELECT * FROM dbo_Person WHERE [date born] = #" & Format(FilterDate, "yyyy\/mm\/dd") & "#;"
```

Comment: One can link with native 11 (or later drivers) to see/use datetime2 correctly. Now then ZERO changes to the client side VBA and query(s) in regards to date columns is required. (this info for is readers here - not the poster here). CRITICAL detail here, is if the query worked before in Access, or code worked before in Access, then the same code, and same queries will and should continue to work without ANY changes. So, if some date format worked previous, it should continue to work without changes. With datetime2, if access sees that as text, then all code breaks.