# Date format in dynamic SQL - VBA in MS Access

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access, dynamic

In Access I have this code. Variable data is type Date, however, when I insert it into dynamic SQL code as string it formats date to 18.04.1994 whereas SQL date needs to be in US format 04/18/1994.

```
Public Function daj_date_notowania(kod As String, data As Date, Optional najpierwStarsze As Boolean = True) As Date
Dim dbs As DAO.Database, rst As DAO.Recordset
Dim sql As String

Set dbs = CurrentDb
Set rst = dbs.OpenRecordset("SELECT wartosc from [Notowania] " & _
"where kod = '" & kod & "' and data = #" & data & "#")
```

Even when I add *`Format(data, "mm/dd/yyyy")`* it still formats as 04.18.1994.

This piece of code used to work, however, I upgraded Windows and Access version. I can always do *`Format(data, "mm") & "/" & Format(data, "dd") & "/" & Format(data, "yyyy")`* and it works, but doing this in whole code looks like a nightmare.

I use Polish version of Windows and Access.

Can any one help me?

Comment: see if one of these help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17361338/convert-string-to-date-in-ms-access-query

Comment: Use a properly parameterized query then you won't have conversion problems as the value is already a date. For VBA use a `QueryDef` and set the `Parameters` property.

Comment: Here is how: [Managing Dates Query in ACCESS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72303508/3527297).